# react-apple-login can't get socialID

Tags: reactjs

while using react-apple-login for login a get either code or id_tiken, but both of them are dynamic and different every time.

the task is to get user social id which I will be able to compare with user IDs we have on a server.

my code looks like this:

```
<AppleLogin
clientId="client.id"
redirectURI="https://redirect.uri"
usePopup={false}
callback={(event: any) => appleResponse(event)}
responseMode="fragment"
responseType="code id_token"
render={(renderProps) => (
<button
className="buttonSocialPortrait whiteBlock ml10"
onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
<AppleDark />
<p className="regularText fs16 fw500 textBlack pl10">
Apple ID
</p>
</button>
)}
/>
```

as a result i get sth like this:

```
https://redirect.uri/#code=c65b613d29f6542b2b80e9014bf8ebd00.0.mrzuv.VPn09HVkbab4TEUHtzH10Q&id_token=eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBwLmd1YmFkb28ud2ViIiwiZXhwIjoxNjkxNzM3MDkxLCJpYXQiOjE2OTE2NTA2OTEsInN1YiI6IjAwMTk0NS5mNTMwYzgwZmUyZTg0Y2Q3YTI0NmU3ODkxNGYxZWU1MS4xMDQzIiwiY19oYXNoIjoibm14dXRNanJDYnlpaFdlb3ZMYXJGZyIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTY5MTY1MDY5MSwibm9uY2Vfc3VwcG9ydGVkIjp0cnVlfQ.aG-HR23BM6TD0zT2MY__vxQl1oCUrAKERLeAeGw7yfiOAWXfDYc-ddTCVKWsObLzMp3ygXnnx_0xgPKnznDgBbEuYu_V65TLxNZjjrUuqxAKuv6OKSaIHKO2ApE_pNXshxcALoZyVgM-rtfTHUN189RaPiOlkJbBVoJ3wQZMgq2B5bZ9qkmvCNHWoMbGWD_Z27mRC2-P9Z6ksS8kPMzHflLhrfmCjmwUp3VAWN8pVE3UG01qBl-RDmtWk4Y6TSpZsahLayeXVIvMsTGaaZO_tSjBgU_4SQ6Sdu-f2UctGaFTL6yxUPQj5y-EU35_eNpuLMfBh_ye5488LYebEdxiIQ
```

it a redirect and i can get code and id_token from it but never social id

i tried different responseMode but it only works with 'fragment' because 'form_post' get blocked from our backend (get 405)

is there any way to get static social ID?

Comment: you can make an HTTP request and retrieve the data using the ```id_token``` ( scope ... ). Also, you may try to decode the id_token and see if there's the data you need.